# Bootstrap: how to extend input to occupy available space?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I created this example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u69QR/1/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="span4">
            <div style="height:200px; position: relative" class="thumbnail">
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 5px; right: 5px; bottom:5px;">
                    <form style="margin:0;" class="form-inline">
                        <input style="margin: 3px 0 0 0;" type="text" placeholder="Name…" ng-model="mashName" class="pull-left span3" />
                        <button type="submit" style="margin: 3px 0 0 0; " class="span1 btn btn-primary pull-right">Create</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I need is for the input to extend to the button, without using percentages that screw everything when resizing. This example is very near, but the button is screwed by using span..

`.input-block-level` is nice, but it extends all the way.. instead it should stop just before the button. is there a way to fix this without javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to remove the width that bootstrap places on your input field by overriding it with `width: auto` then use absolute positioning to give the proper widths.. to conform to the width of its containing div.

I created a jsFiddle of this:  http://jsfiddle.net/w8YfL/

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="span4">
            <div style="height:200px; position: relative" class="thumbnail">
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 5px; right: 5px; bottom:5px;">
                    <form style="margin:0;" class="form-inline">
                        <input style="position: absolute; right: 70px; left: 0; bottom: 0; width: auto;" type="text" placeholder="Name…" ng-model="mashName"/>
                        <button type="submit" style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</diV>
```

Comment: Woah! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work (anymore?) in Chrome 56 and Firefox 51.0.1 (both MacOS X). Safari for some reason works. Tried your original fiddle and also tried updating to Bootstrap 3.3.7. :-(